# Equivalent of angular's $q.deferred.reject without $q

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I imagine this has to be a pretty normal setup:

```
return $http.get('some/url')
.then(function (result) {
    if (result.data.success) {
        //Do something useful
    } else {
        //We've hit some sort of error
    }
},
function () {
    return "Failed to communicate with the server, or the server encountered an error.";
});
```

My questions is around what to do about scenarios where the http call technically succeeds, but the data we get back from the server is bad, unusable, or explicitly indicates something is wrong. What I want to do there is push myself onto the failure track of the promise chain. That way anyone consuming this promise well execute their own failure function, if that makes sense.

I know $q gives you the tools you need to do this by creating a deferred object and then letting you call resolve or reject under any circumstance you want, but I wondered if there was a way to do that without using $q.

Comment: The question is, why you want to use a alternative way to do that? $q does exact this job for you with no problems at all.

Comment: @code I guess just to keep it absolutely as simple as possible? And I sorta figured there must be a way. If not, I guess not, but if there were, seems like I ought to know it.

Comment: If you use it like you should, there is no simpler way than this. ;) have an eye on: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Comment: `return Promise.reject(Error(...))` or `throw new Error(...)` inside the `then`.

Comment: $q shouldn't be avoided because *it is already $q promise*. `return $q.reject(...)` does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a promise from the resolved to the rejected state, you can do one of two things from a `.then()` handler:

1. Return a rejected promise and the reason for that rejected promise will become the reject reason for the parent promise.
2. Throw an exception and the exception value will become the reject reason for the parent promise.  `.then()` automatically catches exceptions in `.then()` handler functions and turns them into rejections.

So, here's one way you could do it:

```
return $http.get('some/url').then(function (result) {
    if (result.data.success) {
        //Do something useful
    } else {
        //We've hit some sort of error, make promise become rejected
        throw new Error("invalid data received");
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    // log error
    console.log(err);
    // make sure promise stays rejected
    throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6 you can use JavaScript native promises.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `Promise` promises shouldn't be mixed with Angular `$q` promises without a good reason, this leads to unpredictable results and testing problems.

Comment: Agreed, the best option would be to use $q. But since OP does not want to do that I posted an alternative.